# SuiteCRM 8 htaccess error after install: public/legacy/.htaccess: RewriteBase: argument is not a valid URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, mamp, suitecrm

I am trying to install SuiteCRM-8.2.1  on a server for a client and everything has run fine but there seems to be a .htaccess file problem

This is the error in the dashboard,profile, admin

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at you@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

[core:alert] [pid 67661] [client ::1:62740] /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SuiteCRM/public/legacy/.htaccess: RewriteBase: argument is not a valid URL, referer: http://localhost:8888/SuiteCRM/public/

I am trying to install SuiteCRM on mamp. During the installation above errors encountered.
Pls suggest to me if anyone has a solution

Comment: Quick Answer: Solution is available in Official SuiteCRM 8 documentation https://docs.suitecrm.com/8.x/admin/installation-guide/downloading-installing/#_helpfull_resources_3

Answer (score 0):

Try updating `RewriteBase` to `/public/legacy`

Please also make sure that the `site_url` on `/<your-crm>/public/legacy/config.php` is correct. It should be pointing to your legacy path, something like: `https://<your-host>/public/legacy`

Note: Please note that if your vhost is not directly pointing to `/<your-crm>/public` and you have SuiteCRM installed on a sub-folder like `https://<your-host>/suite-8/public` you will need to add something like `/suite-8/public/legacy` to `RewriteBase`. And something like `https://<your-host>/suite-8/public/legacy` to `site_url` on `config.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I found its solution in the official SuiteCRM 8 docs. Please read below and apply according to your virtual host setup:

> **1. site_url** Legacy config in public/legacy/config.php should be updated:

if the vhost is not pointing to the public directory in your SuiteCRM 8 instance,then, you should append `/public` to your host

> **2. RewriteBase** .htaccess in public/legacy/.htaccess

If the vhost is pointing to /legacy dir within the SuiteCRM 8 instance, then the RewriteBase should have `/legacy`

Otherwise, you will need to prepend the path until the `public` folder.

So, when your address is like https://roigap.com/crm/public, then RewriteBase correct value is `/crm/public/legacy`

Please visit the Official documentation linked below for more details:
https://docs.suitecrm.com/8.x/admin/installation-guide/downloading-installing/